# Hide text if it doesn't fit in one line with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` element which contains some text. This element has fixed width. If the text is so long that it cannot fit in one line, I want to hide that text (the whole text, not just extra lines). Otherwise show the text.

Can this be done with CSS?

Adding some additional elements in html that can help to accomplish this is acceptable.

Comment: You mean you want to hide all of the text if it can't fit? Or just the part that will get cut off?

Comment: @Luka I doubt that's possible. CSS can't "detect" overflow. It can handle it in a few different ways but that's about it. Use javascript.

Comment: Why are there two "missing MCVE" close votes? The asker is not troubleshooting anything here.

Comment: Don't understand. Is the problem that somebody voted to close or is it the problem that not enough people voted to close?

Comment: @Luka The problem is that someone voted to close because you don't show code. But obviously you have no code to show.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. Place your text in an inline-block inner-wrapper with `white-space: nowrap` to prevent line breaks.
2. Insert an empty inline-block pseudo-element before that inner-wrapper.
3. When the inner-wrapper is wider than the outer-wrapper, it will be moved to the second line of the outer-wrapper.
4. To hide it use `overflow: hidden`, and set the same value to `height` and `line-height`.

```css
.outer-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  margin: 1em;
}
.outer-wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
}
.inner-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    this is a short line
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    this is a super long line of text that it is never ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever going to fit on a single line!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is pretty clever.

Comment: This doesn't quite work in safari (at least as of safari 12.0) for me as written, but if instead you replace the `:before` with an element before the .inner-wrapper and give it `display: inline-block; width: 1px;` the technique worked in safari.

Comment: Great solution. But what is the reason of block `.outer-wrapper::before`, seems like it works without as well.

Answer (score 3):

The solutions presented in other comments are out of date, today we have a really **simple** way to do this using `text-overflow`.

> Note: The `text-overflow: string` only works in  **Firefox**.
>
> Note 2: `text-overflow` only occurs when the **container's overflow property** has the **value hidden**, **scroll** or **auto** and `white-space: nowrap;`.

```css
.a {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 50px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.b {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 50px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.c {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 50px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: "----"; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<h1>The text-overflow Property</h1>

<p>The following two divs contains a text that will not fit in the box.</p>

<h2>text-overflow: clip (default):</h2>
<div class="a">Hello world!</div>

<h2>text-overflow: ellipsis:</h2>
<div class="b">Hello world!</div>

<h2>text-overflow: "----" (user defined string):</h2>
<div class="c">Hello world!</div>
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp) you can find an example and a more complete explanation in [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow).

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. In your example you don't hide the text at all. Text should be hidden if it doesn't fit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the extra text, you can do something like:

```css
div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 50em;
    border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<p><br><br></p>

<div>
  this is a super long line of text that it is never ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever going to fit on a single line!
</div>
```

If you want to hide the entire element completely, you will need to use JavaScript. CSS has no way to "detect" if the text is too long.

Comment: I wanted to hide the whole text. I will update my question to emphasize that

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you will need to use JavaScript.