# CSS - removing one of the divs if their content cant fit into one line

Tags: css

I have filename div and filesize div in one line, I would like to remove the filesize div if the
filename is too long (e.g in case of mobile screen because of not enough space)

[aaaaaa.jpg|51Kb] -> [aaaaaaaaaaa.jpg]

Is there any way to do this in CSS or CSS and JS ?

Thanks,
Csaba

**UPDATE**
I have to remove completely the filesize part, to have more space for the filename.

Comment: Please upload some code

Comment: From what you have written I believe some of it might be going offscreen, in that case you can keep the container have a property of overflow:hidden, this will disable scrolling in case content spills over

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37472468/12484098

Comment: I have made an update, overflow hidden is not good, the information cant be hidden partly, must be removed completely

Comment: have you tried  `text-overflow: ellipsis`

Comment: specifically, you want to hide file size on mobile devices only? How about if it's too long on tablet/desktop devices as well?

Comment: mobile device example is just an example, it must behave on every device where there is no enough space for the filename

Comment: After file size removal, what if the file name does not still have enough space? I think you need to clarify that case too.

Comment: You are right (overflow-wrap: anywhere can solve the too long filename - I have tested), but at the moment this is the requirement: hiding the size, I just would like to know is it possible or not and how

Comment: You need to show us more of your HTML structure and related CSS for us to answer this without just guessing. In particular, are those two items within a fixed width container, or within a container with max width or....

Comment: maybe you're looking for `media queries`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least part of the way to do it by using the CSS ::first-line pseudo element.

This snippet sets the font-size of the container to 0 and then sets it back to something for the first-line.

The filename and filesize divs are displayed inline, so the CSS considers them as part of the first line (and the filesize to be not in the first line if the line has been broken at the space).

Note: this gives the right appearance, but it does not remove the filesize div from the DOM, it just makes it have 0 as dimensions.

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  /* this is not essential - put here so you can check */
}

.container::first-line {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.container>* {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="filename">https://aratherlongurlaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div class="filesize">123MB</div>
</div>
```